# ionic update contact info

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I create an Application to Read and Update Contacts Details. Here is a problem to updating Contact email. (I'm using Ionic 3)

When I try to add information to an existing contact the app closes and the console dont show nothing more. I'm using android studio to see the APK in the mobile and does not allow me to update. Here my code:

Update: I got the follow error:
"Wrong type for parameter "properties" of contacts.create: Expected Object, but got String."
"Error in Success callbackId: Contacts1616016237 : TypeError: Wrong type for parameter "properties" of contacts.create: Expected Object, but got String."

I pass the id as a parameter and I look for the contact to update.

```
        UpdateContact(id, email){
            var options = new ContactFindOptions();
            options.filter = id;
            options.multiple = true;

            let proms = [];

            this.contacts.find(["id"], options).then(res=>{res.forEach( (item:Contact) => {

              //console.log(contact);

              proms.push(new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

                  var f = new ContactField('email',email,true);

                  item.emails = [];
                  item.emails.push(f);
                  console.log('FIXED '+item.displayName);
                  item.save().then(() => console.log('Contact saved!'),
                              (error: any) => console.error('Error saving contact.', error)
                              );
                  resolve();

              }))
            })

          })
}
```

Comment: Show the error you get.

Comment: The app closes! And the console dont show nothing more. I'm using android studio to see the APK in the mobile.

Comment: You wrote: "it throws me errors". What errors? Please provide all relevant data and as much details as possible in your question itself (do not use comments), so that you get relevant help.